# how to write this simple code of retrieving values from dictionary in an optimal way (pythonic)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following code

```
  lst = {
  1: 39,
  2: 2,
  3: 1,
  4: 21 }

threshold_value=10
total_value=15
passed = { key:value for key, value in lst.items() if value <threshold_value}
print(passed)
```

Before storing the values that are less than the threshold in the above code, I need the value variable to be divided by variable total_value and multiplied by 100. for instance like this

```
      passed=(lst[k]/total_value)*100
```

How would I write the code in a compact and pythonic way?

Thanks a lot for your wonderful and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is algebraic substitution:

```
passed = { key:value for key, value in lst.items() if value <threshold_value}
```

Turns into

```
passed = { key: (value/total_value)*100 
           for key, value in lst.items() if value <threshold_value}
```

Comment: Are you going to make any comment on the OP's use of `lst` as a variable name for a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
[(v/total_value)*100 for k,v in lst.items() if v < threshold_value]
```